# Accessing Child node's property by js

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to loop through body's childnodes to adjust their width, height and etc. by getting device width but it is showing null.
For html

```
<body><div id="header">Text</div></body>
```

Here the code is for CSS

```
#header{
 width:340px; height:90px;background:#72c9f6;border-radius:10px;
    }
```

And for js

```
    var c=document.body.childNodes;
    for(var i=0;i<c.length;i++){
     if(c[i].nodeName=="#text"||c[i].nodeName=="#comment"){
    continue;
    }else{
    c[i].style.width=screen.width*parseInt(c[i].style.width)/360+"px";
    }
    }
```

But `parseInt(c[i].style.width)` is giving error.
What to do and why it is giving error?
Thanks for help

Comment: You have to initialize `i` with `0`.

Comment: Then also I am not able to do. In the above code I mistakenly forgot to intialise but with my real code I have intialised it but it doesn't work. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined` is the error I am getting

Comment: That means `c[i]` doesn't have a `style` property, so you might be accessing a node that is not an element node. Do `console.log(c[i])` to see what you are dealing with.

Comment: When I do `console.log(c[i])` it gives me the respective dom element ,also when I do `console.log(c[i].style)` it gives me the `CSS Declaration` but there the value of width is `""`.

Comment: Is there some other way to loop through all the child nodes of body element to adjust there width and all?

Comment: You can use `children` instead of `childNodes` to only access element nodes. As for empty `width`: You will have to figure out how to handle that case. Generally though: There shouldn't be a reason to adjust the width of all elements. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I want to do that so all the elements will have the same proportion as it was on my screen. For PCs and computer I will make a separate ui. Is anything wrong with my idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got my answer that is I have to use style property which should be written in the elements start tag like this `<div id="header" style="width:340px;height:90px;....>....</div>`.